# Tie in Presidential Elections

Tags: united-states, presidential-election

What will be the procedure if both Democrat and Republican candidate get equal votes in the presidential elections? Will  recounting be done? Or will re-election take place?

Comment: To clarify, are you aware of the Electoral College in American Elections.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate. If anyone disagrees, please let me know, since I accidentally triggered dupe-hammer unintentionally.

Answer (score 5):

If there is a tie, the vote goes to the House of Representatives to choose the President, or to the Senate to choose the Vice President. This is called a Contingent Election. There is no runoff election or re-vote.

The United States is a bit peculiar in this regard. The 12th Amendment to the Constitution specifies that Electors cast two ballots; one for President, and one for Vice President.  Technically speaking, the two candidates do not have to be from the same party, nor do they even have to be on the same ticket (though in practice, they always run together and are elected together).

Additionally, the Constitution requires that a candidate get an absolute majority of electoral votes, which is currently 270. If no candidate gets at least 270 votes, a continent election is held in Congress even is there was no tie.

This has only happened 3 times in U.S. history:

1. The election of 1800 in which Thomas Jefferson and Aaron Burr tied for President. Thomas Jefferson was elected by a House contingent election. It took 36 ballots to break the tie.
2. The election of 1824 where Andrew Jackson lost to John Quincy Adams in a House contingent election, even though Jackson won both the popular and electoral votes.
3. The election of 1836 where Richard Mentor Johnson (Martin van Buren's vice president) failed to get a majority of electoral votes, but won the Senate contingent election.

If a continent election is held for President, and no candidate receives a majority in the House, they keep casting ballots until the deadlock is broken. This happened in 1800 when 36 ballots had to be cast before Thomas Jefferson emerged with the needed votes.

If, after carrying multiple ballots the House *still* can't reach a decision by March 4th, the elected Vice President becomes President.  There is no deadline for the Senate in voting for Vice President, since the Senate can't really be deadlocked (the outgoing VP would cast the tie-breaking vote). Although if there were no outgoing VP (like if he had resigned just before the election), or there were a tight race between three candidates with none receiving a majority, then they could theoretically be deadlocked.

If by some crazy fluke both the House *and* the Senate are both deadlocked by the March 4th deadline, the Supreme Court would likely have to get involved, since the Constitution doesn't deal with this scenario. Presumably they would rule that the 25th Amendment applies and would follow the line of succession, beginning with the Speaker of the House to fill the Presidency.

Comment: And if there would be a tie too in both Houses?

Comment: @Trilarion there can be a tie in both houses. In that case Congress can pass laws on who is to act as President (25th amendment). Right now the Speaker of the House would do that. Additionally, it's very hard for a tie vote to occur in the Senate, as the old Vice President is still serving when this vote happens and could cast the tie breaking vote.

Comment: @Trilarion; I updated my answer to reflect that contingency.

Answer (score 0):

Elections don't determine a President.  They determine which party's Electoral College electors get to cast their votes for the President and the Vice President.  There are 538 Electoral College electors.  If no party's nominee gets a majority (*50% + 1*) of the ballots, then the House of Representatives gets to vote.

To win, a candidate must receive a majority of ballots in the House (even if it's a 3-way race).  The whole procedure is outlined in the [12th Amendment to the US Constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelfth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution).  There are a few more details there, but you can read the rest for yourself.

Comment: I don't know why the down vote but is it mathematically possible to have a tie in the electoral college.  I may have to write a program to try out all the combinations. Even though there is an even number of delegates, is there a combination of states that would allow a tie?

Comment: Generally a tie in the electoral college is most likely to happen if a 3rd party candidate wins enough elector votes. In strict 2-party voting lines, it's not possible unless electors abstain from the vote.

Comment: Because electors are human beings (who may lie or act on their own accord if they so chose), technically anything is possible.  If they vote against their states' wishes, they would be breaking their states' laws in many states.  But even breaking a state law would not invalidate their votes.